# Import 3rd party javascript libraries in Angular single components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, angular2-components

I'm currently developing an Angular4 application and I want to **import** some **javascript libraries** but **just for a single component**.
Currently I can easily import this libraries by defining their paths inside `.angular-cli.json` like that:

```
{
   "scripts": [
      "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "../node_modules/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js",
      "../src/assets/js/jquery/cometd/org-cometd.js",
      "../src/assets/js/jquery/cometd/jquery.cometd.js",
   ],
   ...
}
```

However, the mentioned scripts will be imported for all the application. Is there a way to import them just for a specific component ?
I've tried to import them inside the component like shown below but without success.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation, Inject } from '@angular/core';
...
import "../../../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
import "../../../../../node_modules/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js";
import "../../../../assets/js/jquery/cometd/org-cometd.js";
import "../../../../assets/js/jquery/cometd/jquery.cometd.js";

@Component({
   selector: '...',
   templateUrl: '...',
   styleUrls: '...',
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
   ...
}
```

**[UPDATE]** - I forgot to mention that I am currently using the **ViewEncapsulation.None** to be able to apply the styles from some css files into the component. Not sure if this detail can be related with the issue.

Comment: you can add them to `document` by using their path from assets folder or cdn `document.head.appendChild(...path);`

Comment: thanks, it seems to work at least for some of the libraries...

Answer (score 2):

Things like jQuery and bootstrap are global and will be available to the application. But, it is good practice to make them injectable and thus referable from single components.

First install jQuery

```
npm install --save jquery
npm install -D @types/jquery
```

Second make an injection module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import * as jquery from 'jquery';

export const JQUERY = new InjectionToken<jquery>('jQuery');

export function _jquery(): jquery {
  return jquery;
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [{
    provide: JQUERY,
    useFactory: _jquery
  }]
})
export class JqueryTokenModule { }
```

Third, in your module:

```
providers: [{provide: JQUERY, useValue: _jquery}]
```

Finally, inject it into your component

```
constructor(@Inject(JQUERY) private $) {
  // use `this.$` which is jQuery
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import them inside component using `import`. For example for `jQuery` it will be

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

which means "import all as '$' (and use it as '$' further) from 'jquery' library", and you don't really need to include another import to `.angular.cli.json`. It works fine for Angular 5 (I have tested it right now), I think, it should work for 2 and 4 versions too. To ensure that it works, you can write `console.log($)` in `ngOnInit` block (for example).

Comment: Using this I still get the console error  `scripts.bundle.js:3186 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`. I've installed jquery via `npm install --save jquery` and removed the reference to the script inside the angular-cli.json

Comment: It's a little strange, because I have generated new Angular 5 project and imported jQuery and it works fine without additional config =/

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am currently using the ViewEncapsulation.None. I'm not sure if this detail could be related...

Comment: @DavidR, I think it shouldn't affect.

Comment: @DavidR try using lowercase  in "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"

Comment: @DavidR try using lowercase "q" in jquery like this  "import * as $ from 'jquery';"  The "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" shows your import has uppercase "Q" that won't work "import * as $ from 'jQuery';"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by fetching the src js and importing it in your component.

Here is an example from a leaflet application I did :

**package.json :**

```
"leaflet.markercluster": "^1.1.0",
"leaflet-draw": "^0.4.12",
```

**random1.component.ts :** with markercluster library example

```
declare const L: any;
import 'leaflet.markercluster';

export function initMarkerCluster(map: L.Map, mapService: LeafletService) {
  // Set the ClusterMarkerLayer
  const cluster = L.markerClusterGroup();
  ...
}
```

**random2.component.ts :** with leaflet.draw library example

```
declare const L: any;
import 'leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw-src';

export function drawPlugin(map: L.Map, mapService: LeafletService) {
  const drawnItems: L.FeatureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
  const drawControl = initDrawControl(drawnItems);
  map.addControl(drawControl);
  ...
}
```

Note : In these leaflet libraries there was the namespace L for Leaflet so I declared a global variable, but you shouldn't need that.

Comment: thanks for your answer ;) what if the js files I want to import are custom files and not from 3rd party ?

Comment: It shouldn't matter and should work the same. Here my imports were targetting the leaflet libraries from `node_modules`, so you just need to change the import path. Once it is imported in the component, it is used at runtime.

If the file doesn't exist, it will tell you that the import is not correct. You can try calling a method from your custom file, it should work the same. Check how those files are made to ensure that it will be working the same way though.

Comment: I have lots of custom js files to import, do I really need to declare a `const` for each one ? These files have mostly global vars and functions declared...

Comment: No, as I said in the final note, this was specific from my leaflet libraries that had everything encapsulated in the namespace `L`. If you only have functions or whatever from your JS files, just importing them should be enough.