# include external javascript file in only specific component.html

Tags: angular

I'm trying to learn Angular 8 currently. I want to include external custom Javascript file in only specific component.html. What Configuration is need Configurations are needed for this?

Comment: Please Refer This Link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081943/angular2-import-external-js-file-into-component

Comment: i saw it but when used it code the my custom js file added as global.

Comment: i want that test.js file to appear as local , in only specific component.html

Answer (score 0):

Either you use a library that you could include in your component :

```
npm install my-library    
import * as myLibrary from 'my-library'
```

Or you could import your Javascript library in your angular.json file in the script section.

You can also refer to this post : 
[How to add external js file in angular 6 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51097346/how-to-add-external-js-file-in-angular-6-library)

Comment: I was just answering,... Before being rude, you could have checked on Stack for an answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173259/import-3rd-party-javascript-libraries-in-angular-single-components